# Remove garbage(#,$) value from any string and drop records that contains only garbage(#,$) value with multiple occurances in multiple columns

Tags: arrays, string, pyspark

I tried  below code for drop records that contains garbage value with multiple occurrences and multiple columns,But I want to remove garbage value form string with multiple occurrences in multiple columns.

**Sample Code :-**

```
filter_list = ['$','#','%','@','!','^','&','*','null']

def filterfn(*x):
     remove_garbage = list(chain(*[[filter not in elt for filter in 
     filter_list] for elt in x]))
     return(reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, remove_garbage, True))

filter_udf = f.udf(filterfn, BooleanType())

original = original.filter(filter_udf(*[col for col in compulsory_fields]))
original.show()
```

In this example "original" is my original dataframe and "compulsory_fields" this is my array(it stores as multiple columns).

**Sample Input :-**

```
  id        name          salary
  #         Yogita          1000
  2         Neha              ##
  3         #Jay$deep##     8000
  4         Priya         40$00&
  5         Bhavana        $$%&^
  6         $%              $$&&
```

**Sample Output :-**

```
  id        name          salary
  3         Jaydeep         8000
  4         priya           4000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not completely clear to me, but it seems you want to output records that are valid after removing the "garbage" characters. You can achieve this by adding a `clean_special_characters` udf that removes the special characters before running your `filter_udf`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from itertools import chain
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace,col
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType,StringType

rdd = sc.parallelize((
     ('#','Yogita','1000'),
     ('2', 'Neha', '##'),
     ('3', '#Jay$deep##','8000'),
     ('4', 'Priya', '40$00&'),
     ('5', 'Bhavana', '$$%&^'),
     ('6', '$%','$$&&'))
 )

original = rdd.toDF(['id','name','salary'])

filter_list = ['$','#','%','@','!','^','&','*','null']

compulsory_fields = ['id','name','salary']

def clean_special_characters(input_string):           
    cleaned_input = input_string.translate({ord(c): None for c in filter_list if len(c)==1})
    if cleaned_input == '':
        return 'null'
    return cleaned_input

clean_special_characters_udf = f.udf(clean_special_characters, StringType())

original = original.withColumn('name', clean_special_characters_udf(original.name))
original = original.withColumn('salary', clean_special_characters_udf(original.salary))

def filterfn(*x):
     remove_garbage = list(chain(*[[filter not in elt for filter in 
     filter_list] for elt in x]))
     return(reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, remove_garbage, True))

filter_udf = f.udf(filterfn, BooleanType())

original = original.filter(filter_udf(*[col for col in compulsory_fields]))
original.show()
```

This outputs:

```
+---+-------+------+
| id|   name|salary|
+---+-------+------+
|  3|Jaydeep|  8000|
|  4|  Priya|  4000|
+---+-------+------+
```